# Get profile2 fields based on user

Tags: database, users

I am trying to retrieve some fields from my [Profile 2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) profile but am not sure how I should connect the table dr_field_data_field_resources to its relevant user.

In profile it is possible to add a field term_reference 'resources', then I want to be able to retrieve those values in an array based on a user I specify. I did see some other docs for [profile2_load](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!profile2.module/function/profile2_load/7), but I using an [example turorial](http://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/get-drupal-7-profile-fields-profile2load). I am getting called to undefined function for `profile2_load()`.

```
$userskillsresources = db_query("SELECT dr_users.name as 'username', dr_taxonomy_term_data.name  as 'userresourceterm'
    FROM dr_users
    JOIN dr_field_data_field_resources
    JOIN dr_profile ON dr_users.uid = dr_profile.uid
    JOIN dr_taxonomy_term_data ON dr_field_data_field_resources.field_resources_tid = dr_taxonomy_term_data.tid
    WHERE dr_users.uid = '10'")->fetchAssoc();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really do have Profile2 installed and enabled, then you shouldn't get getting undefined function errors.  Double check that it is enabled.

Otherwise, you are going about this in the wrong way.  You really don't need to do queries like this.  Leverage the API:

```
$account = user_load(10);
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($account);
```

If you have a single profile for the user, $profile will be a node object.  Otherwise, it will be an array of nodes.  Then you can do something like:

```
$resources = field_get_items('node', $profile, 'field_resources', $profile->language);
```

Also take a look at [this article](http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-7-tip-get-field-values-entity-objects-nodes-users-taxonomy) for a handy helper function or read more about the [Field API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/group/field/7).  If `$resources` are taxonomy terms, then take a look at [taxonomy_term_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7) for loading the associated terms.

Comment: Hi, I am getting  Call to undefined function user_load() and it says for definite that profile2 is installed and enabled...

Comment: would it not work if I was logged in as admin?

Comment: If you are getting an undefined function for `user_load` then you have a serious problem elsewhere.  Off the top of my head I am not sure how I would go about debugging this, other than starting to disable anything custom I did to the site.

Comment: Hi, I didn't do anything custom to the site.

Comment: I am still getting this error. Any suggestions as to steps to take to debug it.

Comment: the answer to the error was that I had edit_profile module also install which I think was messing with things.